# Converting "String*" (Scala) to/from "String..." (Java)

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions, scala-java-interop

I'm converting some of the Elasticsearch Java API to Scala. There are some methods in Java that take a variable of type `String... indices`, so I'm trying to provide a Scala function with a variable of type `indices: String*`, that encapsulates that Java method.
I didn't find a way to convert `String*` to `String...`.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala interoperates with Java vararg functions, so if you knew the arguments, you could just provide them.

But the Scala `String*` will come through as a Scala `Seq`. But you'll want the contents of that `Seq` to be unrolled and provided as arguments to the Java function.

Scala has a special syntax for specifying that the contents of a `Seq` should be unrolled and passed along to a function. You write `: _*` after the name of the `Seq`.

So, it should be something like this:

```
def myScalaFunction( args : String* ) : Unit = {
   javaStringVaragsFunction( args : _* )
}
```

Give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
javaMethod(args: _*)
```

Example:

```
val args = Array("1", "2")
String.format("%s %s", args: _*)
```